# Using Background activity while dialog is opened

Tags: android, dialog

How to use other views in a activity while dialog is opened in Android

Comment: Sorry, that is not an option. Dialogs are in their own window, and only one window of an app can receive input at a time. You would need to not use an actual `Dialog`, but instead render something in the activity itself, where that "something" happens to look like a dialog.